# How do RBAC role bindings and ACLs work in a kafka cluster with MDS running on 1 follower node only?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, rbac

I have a kafka cluster with 1 controller and 2 follower broker nodes.

In one of the follower broker nodes, I change the server.properties, configure MDS and LDAP so all ACLs and RBAC role bindings get stored in MDS. Therefore, on that one follower node only, I have MDS running and not on the other 2 nodes.

Now I restart that one follower node only that has MDS running.

I have the following questions/confusion as I don't know how kafka works internally. I don't find relevant information on confluent documentation either.

1. What will happen if I do RBAC role binding on that cluster using cluster-ID? Will it fail because it will always connect to the controller node which does not have MDS running as RBAC needs MDS?
2. What will happen to any new ACLs that I create? My assumption is that it'll register the ACLs in either zookeeper or MDS depending on the bootstrap server used in kafka-acls command. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Kafka doesn't have concept of "followers"

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Confluent MDS internal topic to have a `replication.factor=3`, then it doesn't matter which broker is which.

> MDS maintains a local cache of authorization data that is persisted to an internal Kafka topic named `_confluent-metadata-auth`

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/configure-mds/index.html

Given that the MDS is an HTTP server, it would be useful to run multiple instances, then front with a load-balancer...

---

The default Authorizer stores ACLs in Zookeeper. If you change the `authorizer.class`, then they can be stored anywhere else.

> depending on the bootstrap server used in kafka-acls

Sounds like you only have one cluster. Bootstrap server string defines a whole cluster (it accepts a CSV list), not one server in a cluster.